# Where to find information about how Layout Managers work (Layout Managers internals)?

Tags: javascript, layout-manager

Put in an answer or link to some page with information about how Layout Managers work (Layout Managers internals)?

in general matter. For laying 2d (normal) components in a browser. I want to build a layout manager for an application framework in javascript

Comment: Layout managers for laying out _what_ and on _which_ framework or platform?

Comment: in general matter. For laying 2d (normal) components in a browser. I want to build a layout manager for an application framework in javascript.

Comment: so is there anything my answer doesn't answer that you are still looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have a grasp of your question, the quintessential tasks a layout manager performs are namely:

- Keep track of position information for each layout component. In a browser can go as far as meaning you can map the relationship of css positioning top, left, absolute, relative, etc.. including the affects of margins, padding, borders, etc..
- This may be viewed as the same point, but keeping track of layers (usually z-index in your case) is also important.
- Tracking shape information, usually height and width of a box
- Track which components have 'active elements' such as scripts, animations, forms or embeds
- Track which components must be attached to others with certain requirements and which are self-contained and widget-like
- Often the capability of dynamically updating styling properties and even content within a given layout component
- Providing functionality to reposition, align, resize and otherwise adjust tracked properties of one layout component based on the properties of one or more other layout components

If you are capable of handling this, you are on to a good start. Being able to take it a step further by designing layout formats that may be rearranged based on a template or schema can also be very useful.

---

> **Update**: As far as which size takes
>   precedence, I'm unsure what you are
>   looking for. If you are already using
>   JavaScript it can be good practice to
>   keep width between min- and max- width
>   dynamically along side the css to keep
>   cross-browser.
>   Reading the node structure and handling it is somewhat a matter of
>   preference and *very much* a matter of
>   design. In my own experience it is
>   nice to abstract the child-most
>   'layer' of nodes, well particularly
>   all the content holding nodes into one
>   part of code and the parent-most nodes
>   in another. These are not strictly the
>   top and bottom nodes however as some
>   content does have sub-nodes, `<b>`
>   tags for instance. After that I fill
>   in another abstraction for containers
>   and finally account for all nodes
>   using the relationship of these three
>   layers.
>
> If you arrange the 'main' elements using relative lengths such as em, ex,
>   etc.. or percentages and follow up
>   using absolute positioning on children
>   either in a `<div style="position:
>   relative">` wrapper or using margins
>   to add or subtract from the relative
>   lengths,.. you are able to produce
>   closely matching displays across
>   different browsers *and* different
>   end-user screen resolutions.
>
> Also, take a look at basic HTML/CSS design best practices for
>   reference and try to simply implement
>   them and you'll be off to a good
>   start.

Comment: I would need information regards the order of the passes. ex: first measure inner children, then outer children... or what is the most predominant between size, min-size, max-size, percent-size and so on. How to measure... and all these stuff..

Comment: Well just implementing min-height in a cross-browser way could be a new question on it's own but I will try to put something together on this in the morning. :) I will say I have found the need to become familiar with the differences in element.offsetHeight, offsetLeft, offsetParent, offsetTop, offsetWidth, offsetX, offsetY and their respective element.height etc,.. values. Boiled down they represent values post- and pre- page render. Their relationship is very useful in dynamic resizing/reposition with JavaScript.

Comment: Hy! all the positioning and resizing I plan to be done in js. the js only sets the top, right, bottom, left, width, height in css. the min/max-width/height is done in js. This is the only way I see it crossbrowser and no stress! xD check this: http://www.slideshare.net/tottys/web-application-with-just-javasc

Comment: Looks like a good system to me =D js can do most of what you can accomplish in flash while reaching a few extra users :) With the ability to set the layout dynamically, you can make a tweening function rather easily using by incrementing CurrentPosition towards DestinationPosition with a timestep and a timer. There are all sorts of things you probably have already started thinking up. Will check this out as it grows!